# Can I mount an external library to a react component

Tags: reactjs

I have to use an external library for payments called Yoco, and to use it they say I should put the script link in the `<head>`, then create a form with an id of "card-frame" and then run the following script:

```
<script>
  var sdk = new window.YocoSDK({
    publicKey: 'pk_test_example12345678' 
  });

  // Create a new dropin form instance
  var inline = sdk.inline({
    layout: 'field',
    amountInCents: 2499,
    currency: 'ZAR'
  });
  // this ID matches the id of the element we created earlier.
  inline.mount('#card-frame');
</script>
```

It is best practice in React to mount something to a component with the .mount() method, or is there a different way that I should do it?

I'm not even exactly sure what the "mount()" is supposed to do because if I log the "inline" element I just get this object:

```
{
    layout: 'field',
    amountInCents: 2499,
    currency: 'ZAR'
  }
```

So I have no clue where the form elements (like the buttons and fields) come from since they are not in the "inline" element. But if I put this in vanilla HTML it does generate a form.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice in React to load external libraries is to use `useEffect`. You can include the link to the library in the `head` of your app and then use the `useEffect` hook to initialize it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).